# net::ERR_ABORTED at page.goto(url) XML

Tags: url, request, puppeteer, goto

I have been stuck sending `DELETE` request from `puppeteer.await`

`page.goto(url)` is causing an error "net::ERR_ABORTED at url".

The url forwards to XML file.

I succeeded `POST` with same method but not with `DELETE`. What's the issue?
Could you give me full example of `DELETE` request?

× Delete GPD user (5275ms)

● Visit SCIM › Delete GPD user

```
net::ERR_ABORTED at url (https://test.dev.com:1234/sandbox-s/users/auth0%7C12345)
```

> ```
>  page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
>     var options = { 
>         'method': 'DELETE',
>         'headers': { 'content-type': 'application/json', 'accept': 'application/json', 'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'authorization': 'Bearer ' + GPD_token},
>         'timeout': 10000
>     };
>     interceptedRequest.continue(options);
> }); 
> const response = await page.goto(url);
> ```

```
  at navigate (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:121:37)
    -- ASYNC --
  at Frame.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:110:27)
  at Page.goto (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:629:49)
  at Page.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:23)
  at Object.goto [as deleteUser] (src/pages/gpd/scimPage.js:105:33)
  at Object.deleteUser (src/specs/gpd/scim/visit.spec.js:61:37)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that the server is rejecting the call?

Comment: Was this problem resolved?

Comment: Puppeteer seems to throw this error when the response status is 204 (which DELETE request responses sometimes are). I tested sending a request to a server I control, returning 204 made the Puppeteer client throw the error. Returning 200 worked fine. Only difference in the responses was the status.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to 'solve' the issue / find out why the error is thrown, but here's a workaround which may be suitable:

Watch out for the response, determine if the response is for the request you're trying to intercept (e.g. by checking the URL) and check is the response has what you need.

```
    page.on("response", interceptedResponse => {
        if(interceptedResponse.url() === urlImLookingOutFor){
           // do stuff. interceptedResponse has status(), json() etc methods
        }
    });
```